# Bubble sort of div based on inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sort my divs. All of them share same class. Here is the code. But it's not working.

Script

```html
function sort() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $(".abc").length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < $(".abc").length - i; ++j) {
      var c1 = parseInt($(".abc").eq(j).children(".pop").text());
      var c2 = parseInt($(".abc").eq(j + 1).children(".pop").text());
      if (c1 > c2) {
        var $temp = $(".abc").eq(j).(clone(true));
        $(".abc").eq(j) = $(".abc").eq(j + 1).(clone(true));
        $(".abc").eq(j + 1) = $temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The complete code is here https://jsfiddle.net/4m8eneez/3/

Also i would like to know some better approach than this. Can it be made simpler by using each() ?
Please give a hint for quicksort of these divs as well.

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Why complicate it ? -> **https://jsfiddle.net/4m8eneez/1/**

Comment: Not an added value but -- https://youtu.be/k4RRi_ntQc8?t=48s :)

Comment: @adeneo sort() function is not allowed

Comment: So it's homework then? Shouldn't you be the one figuring this out for school, not us ?

Comment: @adeneo self learning can also make you question yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery.sort` method instead

```js
function sort() {
  var sorted = $('.abc').sort(function(a, b) {
    return +b.textContent < +a.textContent;
  });
  $('#wrapper').html(sorted);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="m1" class="abc">
      <span class="pop">2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="m2" class="abc">
      <span class="pop">3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="m3" class="abc">
      <span class="pop">1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="m4" class="abc">
      <span class="pop">7</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="sort" onclick="sort()">
    Sort
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: Sir i am supposed to do this without sort() function

Comment: @SudhanshuSaini You're allowed to use jQuery but you're not allowed to use built-in sort? Why....

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure if `$(...).html(stuff)` actually converts `stuff` to a string and reparses it as a fragment, but I always assumed that it did. If that's the case, wouldn't `$('#wrapper').empty().append(sorted)` be better?

Comment: then how will i differentiate between bubble sort and quick sort? I am using jquery for selection and swapping only

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I did that just to demonstrate.. Did not emphasize on that approach...

Comment: Also, your sort function should return a signed number, not a boolean: `function sort(a, b) { return +a.textContent - +b.textContent; }`

Comment: Actually, it should return `1`, `-1` or `0`, but booleans work fine as well. I'd go for `localeCompare()`

Comment: @adeneo `.localeCompare()` is for sorting strings by UTF-8 code-points. This is sorting numbers. In addition, the `sort()` function uses `localeCompare()` by default when omitting a function argument. And the number does not have to be `1` `-1` or `0`, you should read documentation before claiming that. It just has to be a signed number, or `0` if the two values are considered equal.

Comment: @Rayon wrong. returning `false` is the same as returning `0`, which tells the comparator that `a` and `b` are equal, not that `a` is not less than `b`. You're also sorting them in descending order in case you didn't notice, I'm not sure if that was your intention.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts – I agree with you.. Basically it is about `To switch` or `Not to switch`.. If value returned is `true` is `Boolean` case, `sort` takes places or otherwise....